# How to place images in a single column in appcelerator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have the following simple code in appcelerator. I am trying to place 2 image one below the other. Actually I have 10 - and I am trying to do

```
image
newline
image
newline
image
```

- Appcelerator Studio, build: 4.5.0.201602170821
- SDK 5.2.0

Code

```
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    backgroundColor:"yellow"
});

var imga = Titanium.UI.createImageView ({
    image: "/png/a.png",
    top: "10px",
    });

var imgb = Titanium.UI.createImageView ({
    image: "/png/b.png",
    top: "20px",

    });

win1.add(imga); 
win1.add(imgb); 
win1.open () ;
```

when I run this in ipad mode, the images are on top of each other. how can I put them in a single file column ?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

By default, the layout of Window is composite. That's mean you must define the coordinates of child element. By example, if your a.png is 40 height, you must define top property of imgb to : `top: 50` (10 top imga + 40 height imga).
You can also use `layout : vertical` to display your child element bellow each other.

And you should not use `px` but `dp` or `%`

I suggest you to read this documentation : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Layouts,_Positioning,_and_the_View_Hierarchy

Comment: thanks - I was reading that document and realized that is so cumbersome - where I have to calculate the sum of each icon height to set next one.  Is there an option to create a table of cell and inside each cell - put an image ?

Comment: Yes, i you won't calculate the coordinates of each icon, you can use layout : 'horizontal' or 'vertical'  on your Window. Horizontal layout set by default all children beside each other and Vertical layout below each other. Tips : if you want adding space, you can set top or left too : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Layouts,_Positioning,_and_the_View_Hierarchy-section-29004895_Layouts,Positioning,andtheViewHierarchy-Layoutmodes

Answer (score 1):

Here is the exact code that game me a simple column of images.

```
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    backgroundColor:"white",
});

var scrollview = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
  showVerticalScrollIndicator: true,
  showHorizontalScrollIndicator: true,
  layout: 'vertical' 
  });


var imga = Titanium.UI.createImageView ({
    image: "/png/a.png",
    top: 0
    });

var imgb = Titanium.UI.createImageView ({
    image: "/png/b.png",
    top: 10
    });

var imgc = Titanium.UI.createImageView ({
    image: "/png/c.png",
    top: 10
    });


scrollview.add(imga,imgb,imgc);     
win.add(scrollview);
win.open () ;
```